# How to add rows with null data dynamically in result table in SQL Server 2012?

Tags: sql-server

[image]

I have this table with 22 rows as above

[image]

I am getting a converted table as above

I created following procedure in order to get result table

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[proc_YS_BAB_IR_Item] 
    @UserId int
AS
BEGIN TRAN
    DECLARE @SqlQry NVARCHAR(MAX);
    SET @SqlQry = N''

    DECLARE @Cnt INT = 1, @EndCnt INT = 25,
            @v_UserId INT = CAST(@UserId AS VARCHAR(MAX));

    CREATE TABLE #TempColumns 
    (
        Calculate_ItemIdentifier VARCHAR(MAX), 
        SeqOrder INT
    )

    WHILE @cnt <= @EndCnt
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO #TempColumns
            SELECT 
                'IR'+ CAST(@Cnt AS VARCHAR(MAX)),
                @Cnt

        SET @Cnt = @Cnt + 1;
    END

    DECLARE @DATA VARCHAR(10), @DATA1 VARCHAR(10) = '000000'
    DECLARE @zero_str VARCHAR(6) = '000000'

    -- Generate table alike to yours    
    DECLARE @yourTable TABLE ([value] varchar(max))

    -- convert array to xml
    ;WITH cte AS 
    (
        SELECT  
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS rn,
            [response],
            CAST('<a>'+REPLACE(SUBSTRING([response],2,LEN([response]) - 2),',','</a><a>')+'</a>' as xml) AS x,
            @v_UserId AS UserId,
            [item_identifier]
        FROM  
            #TempColumns 
        LEFT JOIN 
            YS_BAB_response_dump ON YS_BAB_response_dump.Item_Identifier = #TempColumns.Calculate_ItemIdentifier
                                 AND UserId = CAST(@UserId AS VARCHAR(MAX)) 
                                 AND TestModel = 'IR'
    )
    -- do the stuff
    SELECT  
        c.rn,
        c.[response],
        c.[item_identifier],
        RIGHT(@zero_str + 
CAST(SUM(CAST(STUFF(@zero_str,t.c.value('.','tinyint')+1,1,'1') AS INT)) AS VARCHAR(6)), 6) AS ans,
        c.UserId
    FROM 
        cte c
    CROSS APPLY 
        x.nodes('/a') AS t(c)
    GROUP BY 
        c.rn, c.[response], c.UserId, c.[Item_Identifier]
    ORDER BY
        c.rn 

COMMIT TRAN
```

What changes I need to do in above procedure to get 25 records as a result instead of 22, For IR21,IR22 and IR25 I want null data in response and ans columns for that respective userId? May i need to use some other function instead of CROSS APPLY? How it will be?

Comment: First you need a table listing everything - a table that contains IR1 to IR24, _including_ IR 22 etc. Then you need to _outer join_ that your existing dataset

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid - I don't have permission to change original table that is first one.

Comment: How do you know that IR22 exists? A list of these should be in a table somewhere. If not, how do you know it stops at IR24?

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid - I filter that table with test model IR and UserId . So I am getting that list upto IR24. And the fix requirement is that i have to add missing columns inbetween IR1 to IR25 with user ID in result table with NULL data

Comment: Yes and to do that you need a list of all of the IR's that should exist. It looks like you should have the full list already in `#TempColumns`. Possibly you need to use `OUTER APPLY` instead of `CROSS APPLY`

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid - Outer Apply worked . Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You were almost there. Use `OUTER APPLY` instead of `CROSS APPLY`